# fluid mechanics

Tags: fluid

[image]

in question A2 part (ii) why P2 is considered to be zero

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what you have tried to do to solve your problem or what thoughts you have. This site will help you to find the flaws in your process, but we typically do not provide full solutions to homework.

Answer (score 3):

P2 is given as atmospheric and P1 is given as a gauge pressure of 80kN/m^2.

The gauge is assumed to measure the pressure against atmospheric ie it could be a Bourdon tube type gauge.

Which means if atmospheric is taken as 1 then the inlet pressure would be 80 + 1 kN/M^2 absolute. Then, one would subtract 1 from the 81 to get the pressure difference...

Comment: atmospheric pressure is 1. however, in this particular question are supposed to consider the atmospheric pressure "zero"

Comment: @azher for the difference between gauge and absolute pressure, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_measurement. It is 0 because measured relative to atmospheric pressure.

Comment: @azher Consider that what is important here is the pressure _difference_; which is a reason why gauge pressure can commonly be given in some applications instead of absolute pressure.

Comment: @azher Aargh - don't mix up units! Atmospheric pressure is about 101.3 kN/m^2 at sea level, not "1".  But of course the value doesn't matter since P1 is a *gauge* pressure not an absolute pressure.